# If $F_X(z) > F_Y (z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$ then $P(X < Y ) > 0$?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function

I came across this question in a review of an old exam I took.  I didn't get the answer correctly then, and I'm struggling to figure the answer out now.  Can anyone help me reason through this?

> Prove or Disprove that if $F_X(z) > F_Y (z)$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$ then $P(X < Y ) > 0$.  **We may not assume independence**.

Here is what I attempted:

I figured I might be able to approach this by proving this through contradiction.  I started by assuming $P(X<Y)=0$.  Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{X}(z)=P(X\le z) & = & P(X\le z,X<Y)+P(X\le z,X\ge Y)\\
 & = & 0+P(X\le z,X\ge Y)
\end{eqnarray*}

Can anyone help from here?

Comment: This isn't true.  Does the question ask you to assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @whuber, sorry, I wasn't clear about this earlier.  The question asks to prove OR disprove that this is true.  We may NOT assume independence.

Comment: I found counterexamples by considering discrete variables supported on $\{0,1,2\}$ and constructing a table with given marginals (nearly satisfying your requirements, for of course the two distribution functions must agree on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(,\infty)$) and distributing the probability within the tables to make $\Pr(X\lt Y)$ very small.  This provides the insight; such near-counterexamples are readily modified into genuine counterexamples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, it is worth noting that the antecedent condition in your conjecture is a slightly *stronger* version of the condition for [strict first-order stochastic dominance (FSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order) $X \ll Y$, so it implies this stochastic dominance relationship.  This condition is much stronger than what you actually need to get the result in the conjecture, so I will give you a proof for a stronger result (same implication but with a weaker antecedent condition).  Your chosen method of proof is a good one, and you are *almost there* - just one more step to go!

---

> **Theorem:** If $F_X(z) > F_Y(z)$ for *some* $z \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\mathbb{P}(X<Y) > 0$.

---

> **Proof:** We will proceed using a proof-by-contradiction.  Contrary to the result in the theorem, suppose that $\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=0$.  Then for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ you have:
>   $$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
> F_X(z) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant z) 
> &= \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant z, X < Y) + \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant X \leqslant z) \\[6pt]
> &= 0 + \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant X \leqslant z) \\[6pt]
> &= \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant X \leqslant z) \\[6pt]
> &\leqslant \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant z) = F_Y(z), \\[6pt]
> \end{aligned} \end{equation}$$
>   which contradicts the antecedent condition for the theorem.  This establishes the theorem by contradiction.  $\blacksquare$

Comment: Ah, yes of course!  I don't know how I didn't see those last few steps earlier!  Thank  you, @Ben.  This is very helpful.  I appreciate the FSD info too!

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and continuous,
\begin{align*}\Bbb P(X<Y)&=\Bbb E^Y[\Bbb I_{X<Y}\mid Y]\\ &=\Bbb E^Y[F_X(Y)]\\&>\Bbb E^Y[F_Y(Y)]\\ &=\int_{\Bbb R} F_Y(y) \, \text{d}F_Y(y) \\&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Bbb R} \, \text{d}F_Y^2(y)\\&=\frac{1}{2}F_Y^2(\infty)-\frac{1}{2}F_Y^2(-\infty)\\&=1/2\end{align*}
Further,
$$\int_{\Bbb R} F_Y(y) \,\text{d}F_Y(y)=\int_{\Bbb R} \Bbb P(Y'<y) \,\text{d}F_Y(y)$$
when $Y'\sim F_Y(\cdot)$, or
$$\int_{\Bbb R} F_Y(y) \,\text{d}F_Y(y)=\Bbb P(Y'<Y)$$
when $Y,Y'\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} F_Y(\cdot)$, implying
$$\int_{\Bbb R} F_Y(y) \,\text{d}F_Y(y)=1/2$$

Comment: You could have stopped at the first line by noting that $F_Y(y) \ge 0$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$ implies $\mathbb{E}^Y[F_Y(Y)] \gt 0.$   I don't fully believe the rest of the calculation because I can find discrete variables $Y$ where this expectation does not equal $1/2.$  A uniform distribution on $\{0,1,2\}$ will work as a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I cannot assume independence. I've updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: @whuber: right and right. I assumed continuity in addition to independence.